# Union of Several Large Dataframes with Spark Failing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running across the following Problem: I have around 15 .csv files, each 200GB, all the same schema that I want to filter and subsequently boil down into one large Spark Dataframe (using Jupyter with PySpark as frontend).

Loading the CSV files, filtering and persisting them gives me 15 Dataframes that when cached in memory take 1GB each. I then want to union all of them.

However, using the following Snippet fails, crashing the SparkContext.

Result is a cryptic

> Diagnostics:   Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout

```
from functools import reduce  # For Python 3.x
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

def unionAll(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)

# parts was created by doing sth like 
# parts = [load_and_filter(file) for file in csv_files]
comp = unionAll(*parts)
```

If anyone could help me (or even try to guide me where I can find more detailed logs...) that would be nice.

Best Regards,
Zahlii

Comment: You could try increasing spark.network.timeout, might help. This possibly  suggest there's GC pressure, so you could try increasing executor heap.

Comment: I am right now trying to combine the CSVs by putting them all into one load(CSV1,CSV2,..CSVN) at the start. Will re-evaluate whether it worked :)